# Revel app with local packages in heroku

Tags: heroku, go, import, revel

I am trying to deploy a revel app in heroku, in which I have this folder structure:

```
+Base
    +app
        +controllers
            -app.go
        +views
        +models
            -user.go
        +routes
    +conf
    +public
    +test
    .godir
```

In `app.go` I try to include models and routes doing this:

```
import("base/app/models")
```

I am able to run app in local, and after I can use `models.User`. I had tried to make a lot of ways to import these local packages in heroku:

```
import("../models")
import("../models/user")
import("./app/models")
import("./base/app/models")
```

I don't remember now all attempts, but I am trying it for a long time and I don't know ho to do.

I am using locally go 1.6, and 1.4 when I push. And this is the trace that appears when I run `git push heroku master`

```
Counting objects: 93, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (86/86), done.
Writing objects: 100% (93/93), 11.68 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 93 (delta 50), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Revel app detected
remote: -----> Using go1.4
remote: -----> Running: go get -tags heroku ./...
remote: can't load package: /tmp/build_02574263f0810eec437968b2e73f635d/.go/src/base/app/controllers/gorp.go:10:2: local import "../models" in non-local package
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Revel app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to ndc-console.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/ndc-console.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ndc-console.git'
```

It happens using `import("base/app/models")`.

Any solution?? Thank you.

**EDIT**

I log into heroku bash (running `heroku run bash`) and I see the folder structure, and it is something like:

```
bin
dev
more...
app /*This is the base folder*/
    app
        controllers
        views
        models
        routes
    config
    public
    .go /*this is the GOPATH*/

        src
            github.com
            golang.org
            gopkg.in
            base-test /* This name is because I change the original name, from base-test to base... */
            /* IS IT IMPORTANT? */
            /* Inside this folder the app is duplicated */
```

In this way I tried too `import("base-test/app/models")` and too including all path from root (trying absurd things).

I hope it helps to find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: don t use relative path imports. Use package path `absolute_package_path.substr($GOPATH.length)`

Comment: Thanks @mh-cbon but... I don't understand you so well. I tried to use absolute path, or that I think (how you can see on my editing).  For example using `import("base/app/models")` or `import("base-test/app/models")`.  Can you be a litle more concrete, please??

Comment: all user package must exist within GOPATH. Assuming you move the first `app` under `.go/src`, controllers package path would be `app/app/controllers`.

Comment: so yeah that s right, should have been `absolute_package_path.substr($GOPATH.length + 'src/'.length)`

Comment: Hi @mh-cbon. Sorry, but I continue without understand. If I type absolute_package_path I get a compilation error, the same with $GOPATH. So, I can't make `import(absolute_package_path.substr($GOPATH.length + 'src/'.length))`

Comment: Ok!! Done. Thanks @mh-cbon, every advise is wellcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ok!!! done!!

Finally, the old name of the project was generating a problem. It seems that when I change the name of the heroku app, heroku doesn't change the name of the folder when it will be compiled... AND I need change too the content of the .godir file and set it as `base-test` (the old name).

So now the imports I have looks like: `import("base-test/app/models")`.

Thank you everyone.